# Corrigir valor ainda dentro da View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Gostaria de saber como eu posso alterar o valor do @Model
ainda na view, antes de enviar para o servidor e qual a melhor 
maneira de fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```
   @{

       var model = (Pessoa)Model

       bool isAtivo = pessoa.IsAtivo
   }

   @Html.TextBox("Ativo", @isAtivo, new{...})

   Alterar

   Salvar
```

E caso meu item seja uma string como deveria ser feito?

Exemplo 2:

```
   @{

       var model = (Pessoa)Model

       string nome = pessoa.Nome
   }

   @Html.TextBox("Ativo", @nome, new{...})

   Alterar

   Salvar
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: O exemplo exibido é somente demonstrativo.. pois na real eu tenho uma lista de objeto onde eu quero alterar o (bool)status dos objetos da minha lista sem ficar fazendo requisição ao servidor pra cada alteração...

Comment: Ah, então vamos lá. Você tem uma lista de objetos em `@Model`. Você quer alterar o status de alguns dos itens dela. É só em tela ou a alteração tem que refletir imediatamente em servidor?

Comment: Primeiramente quero modificar tudo em tela para depois
estar encaminhando minha lista pronta para o servidor;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o bom e velho `<form>`:

```
@Html.BeginForm() { ... }
```

Como é uma coleção de registros, é bom usar o [pacote BeginCollectionItem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem). Com ele, cada um desses objetos pode ser representado por uma parte do seu formulário.

Suponha que seu model é uma coleção ou enumeração de objetos:

```
@model IEnumerable<Objeto>
```

Você precisa escrever um formulário para ele e iterar os registros de forma a criar todos os campos. Por exemplo:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var objeto in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialFormularioObjeto", objeto)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
}
```

A *Partial*, por sua vez, teria:

```
@model Objeto

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Objetos"))
{
    // Coloque aqui os campos do objeto.
}
```

O *Controller*, por sua vez, receberia:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Enviar(IEnumerable<Objeto> Objetos)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Não consegui entender bem como fazer para alterar o valor antes de ir para o controle?

Comment: Se o status é um `bool`, você tem que usar um `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` para representá-lo. Ou um `@Html.HiddenFor()`, mas acredito que sua intenção é mostrar a informação para o usuário.

Comment: Mas ai ele vai alterar o valor do bool no Enviar() ?

Comment: Se tiver como um campo do formulário, ele pode alterar. Lembra que te perguntei qual o objetivo disso? Você não falou ainda.